# How do I queue up a list of table rows and do a slideUp() or slideDown() in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Say I have a table with 50 rows.  I have parent/child relationships in that table.  I'm trying to click on a parent row and expand/collapse all the children rows.  I have that working, but I want to slideUp the set of rows as one set.  How would I do this?

Say the user clicks on a link in a tr.  Here is an example function of when a user clicks a link inside the row.  Note the TODO:  That is what I'm trying to solve.

```
  var row = $(this).closest("tr")

    while(true) {

       if(parseInt(row.attr("data-Level"), 10) > selectedRowLevel)
{
    // TODO: I want to put all these rows in a queue maybe and the slideUp all together, not just row by row.
    row.slideToggle();
}
else
break;

row = row.next();

}
```

Comment: I'm basically recreating the tree view behavior in this DevExpress grid control.  So your saying it is impossible to show some slide up or down animation on table rows?  http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxTreeListDemos/Selection/FocusedNode.aspx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add a new class to all these specified rows.

Then execute a `slideUp()` or `slideDown()` on that newly created class.

Comment: This is a simple workaround that solved my question of how to group together the show/hide of table rows.  I've implemented this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't slide table rows up or down with JavaScript. You can only show/hide them. This is just a limitation in how tables are rendered.

Only block-level elements can be animated this way. If you replaced the rows with divs and the cells with fixed-width spans, you can get the animation.

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/WgN2N/

HTML:

```
<div class="tr">
    <span class="td">asdf</span>
    <span class="td">qwer</span>
    <span class="td">zxcv</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.td {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #eee;
}
.tr {
    display: block; 
}
​
```

Comment: +1 for explaining to me about the animation on table rows and showing me an alternative technique.